# How to move a row that has data-search attributes to another table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to move a selected row in my DataTable to another DataTable. I have this almost working but the problem is with the cells that have data-search attributes on them. That data just gets placed into my other table as `[object Object]`. I've tried finding an example on how to handle this case in the documentation but I'm not having any luck. Here is what I have..

https://jsfiddle.net/dmcgrew/x85o0mgL/5/

HTML..

```
<table id="selected_items">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Crest Allowed</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>



<table id="select_items">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Crest Allowed</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr id="1">
                        <td data-search="test">1</td>
                        <td>Testing Bowl</td>
                        <td data-search="nocrest">NO</td>
                        <td><button class="button select">Select</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-search="test">32</td>
                        <td>Cup Test</td>
                        <td data-search="nocrest">NO</td>
                        <td><button class="button select">Select</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-search="pristine">3335</td>
                        <td>Bowl Test</td>
                        <td data-search="nocrest">NO</td>
                        <td><button class="button select">Select</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-search="pristine">120</td>
                        <td>Plate Test</td>
                        <td data-search="yescrest">YES</td>
                        <td><button class="button select">Select</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-search="test">1000</td>
                        <td>Mug Test</td>
                        <td data-search="yescrest">YES</td>
                        <td><button class="button select">Select</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-search="pristine">65</td>
                        <td>Ramekin Test</td>
                        <td data-search="yescrest">YES</td>
                        <td><button class="button select">Select</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

JS...

```
var select_items = $('.select_items').dataTable();
var selected_items = $('#selected_items').DataTable();

$('.select_items').on("click", "button.select", function(){
    var selectedRow = select_items.api().row( $(this).parents("tr") ).data();   
    selected_items.row.add(selectedRow).draw(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is the data.
When a td has a data attribute (data-search), it is included in the data object so your data array looks like this:
[{display:"1", @data-search:"test"}, "Testing Bowl", {display: "NO", @data-search: "nocrest"}, "Select"] so first and third items in the array are, in fact objects, hence [object, object]

so the quickest (not the best in my mind) is to alter the data before you add it.

```
select_items.on("click", "button.select", function(){
    var selectedRow = select_items.api().row( $(this).parents("tr") ).data();
    console.log(selectedRow);
        selectedRow[0] = selectedRow[0].display;
      selectedRow[2] = selectedRow[2].display;
    selected_items.row.add(selectedRow).draw(true);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x85o0mgL/12/

Comment: I would also put the data in json instead of html and use the DataTable and use the render function to create the button.